# Difference between select() and fcntl()

Tags: c, unix, select, file-descriptor, fcntl

The way I understand it - we can use `fctnl` to mark a file descriptor as non-blocking, so whenever we call any blocking operation on that file descriptor, it would error and modify `errno` to indicate that the file descriptor isn't ready yet. The responsibility is on us to frequently poll the file descriptor and read or write whenever it is ready.

With `select`, we pass in three arrays(read, write and except) of file descriptors and then `select` polls the file descriptors for a given time interval, modifying the arrays to indicate which file descriptors are available for specified action. And `select` itself is a blocking operation.

Now my doubts are:

1. Lets say I call `select` on an array file descriptors that needs to
   be read and it times out without detecting any events. Now if I call
   `read` on one of file descriptors, will it block or will it return
   E_WOULDBLOCK / E_AGAIN, even if I haven't used `fcntl` first?
2. I call select with a timeout of 10s to check only on a single file
   descriptor. And the data is available to be read on the file
   descriptor almost immediately. In this case, will select still block
   for 10 seconds?

Comment: Most of the time you'd need to use **both** at the same time especially when dealing with sockets. For example, one being that `select` may say a *socket* is ready to be read on Linux, but the buffered packet has incorrect checksum - it is *only* checked upon `read`. If there is not even one byte to read, `read` will then block... therefore both at the same time.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks, @AnttiHaapala

Comment: I.e. my point is that if you think non-blocking sockets are usually busy-looped over, then you're wrong - `select` should be used instead and the 2 are complementary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If `select()` times out but you go to read a blocking file descriptor that is not ready, then you will block.  The call to `select()` does not affect the behaviour of the file descriptor at all.
2. If data is ready immediately, the `select()` call will return immediately.  If the data is ready after 1 second, the `select()` call will return after 1 second.  It will only return after 10 seconds if no data was ready during that time (or if the data arrived just fractionally before the timeout occurred).